# #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sql

estoy haciendo una series de métodos de una clase que sirve para gestiona una pequeña biblioteca de ejemplo que he hecho en una base de datos en local. Las sentencias SELECT funcionan sin problema, pero al ir a borrar filas, simplemente no hace nada. He usado la función `ffected_rows` para y pone 0 filas afectadas. En cambio, si lo hago la consola SQL de la bases de datos (PHP MyADMIN) me da este error:

#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`libros`.`libro`, CONSTRAINT `fk_autor_libro` FOREIGN KEY (`id_autor`) REFERENCES `autor` (`id`))

Tengo 2 tablas: autor y libro. El ID de la tabla autor es la clave primaria. En la tabla libro, ID_autor es la clave foránea que enlaza con la primaria de la tabla autor.

¿Alguna pista? Os dejo mi código:

```
   function borrarAutor($autor) {

       $this->autor = $autor;

       $query = "DELETE FROM autor WHERE id = $autor";

       $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion(), $query);

       echo "Se han borrado " . $this->conexion()->affected_rows . " fila(s)";     

       $resultado = mysqli_close($this->conexion());

  }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leas la teoría del enlace, te ayudará a entender por qué obtienes ese error y en consecuencia darle solución

Comment: Estoy leyendo todo y probando, estoy intentando cambiar la clave foránea para que en caso de DELETE quede NULL. A ver si lo logro pero creo que voy por buen camino.

Comment: @BetaM me ha servido de ayuda y ha funcionado. Cambié la restricción ON DELETE a SET NULL y listo, ya funcionó!

Answer (score 1):

analizando un poco rápido tu problema, creo que el autor no puede ser borrado porque está referenciado en algún registro de tu tabla libro, es decir hay un libro que esta usando ese autor que deseas eliminar y por eso te da ese error, la solución podría ser que primero borres el libro que esta haciendo uso del autor o que actives la eliminación en cascada. Saludos!

Comment: Buenas, sí, el autor está usando 3 libros. Lo haría en cascada pero la primera parte del ejercicio tiene que ser eliminar el autor, pero dejando los libros tal cual. La segunda parte es hacerlo en cascada y eso creo que podré.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que desactivar el contraint que te esta bloqueando el delete en la base de datos, para que te permita hacer eso